# S3 static website on double sub-subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I want to host a static website on a sub-subdomain, for example on `sub1.sub2.domain.com`

1. Created a bucket named `sub1.sub2.domain.com`
2. Added a policy to allow `getObject` publicly
   At this point `http://sub1.sub2.domain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` serves the website
3. Tried adding a DNS rule for sub1.sub2.domain.com like so:

   - CNAME(alias) value sub1.sub2.domain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com - doesn't work, i get this error when saving: The record set could not be saved because: - Alias Target contains an invalid value.
   - A(alias) value sub1.sub2.domain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com - same error

I've done the same thing for another static website hosted under only a subdomain (not a sub-subdomain).

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type: **A**

Alias: **Yes**

Alias Target: **s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com**

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: doesn't work for me. i can save the dns rule but i still get `This site can’t be reached` in the browser.
I tried using the test record set feature from route 53 and this is what i get:

DNS request sent to Route 53
sub1.sub2.domain.com.     IN     A
EDNS0 client subnet IP
24
DNS response code
NOERROR
Protocol
UDP
Response returned by Route 53
54.***.***.**

Comment: well as long as you have enabled website feature for the bucket, and bucket name is identical to your DNS, it must work, unless you have other configuration issues with your hosted zone, are you able to access other DNS records within same hosted zone ?

Comment: we are in the process of moving from a domain to another so i don't have other dns records in the zone. i will check and get back to you

Comment: I guess it's a problem with the name servers. My client has registered the domain directly in AWS. I'm a bit confused because i can see 3 different values of the NS in Route 53:
1. under `registered domains` one set of name servers
2. under hosted zones, by clicking on the domain (not the radio button) a panel opens in the right side of the screen and it lists another set of name servers
3. then if i click on the hosted zone, there is a DNS rule NS having another set of name servers...

Comment: So yeah, it seems like another member of our team has changed the NS copying them from another domain we were managing and got us into this problem. After fixing it and waiting a good amount of time, problem has been fixed by following your directions (something that I have tried before actually). Many thanks